# Error in SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, sql-like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guest WHERE ";
if ($_POST['include2'] == "yes") {
$guestNameLast = isset($_POST['guestNameLast']) ? $_POST['guestNameLast'] :     '';
$query .= "guestNameLast LIKE '%$guestNameLast%' ";
$msg .="guest that <b>" . $guestNameLast . "</b><br/>";
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'guestNameLast LIKE '%%'' at line 1.
How do I fix this error?

Comment: Print/log $query before it runs so you can see what the generated SQL is

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because if the `post` data is not available the `WHERE` will be present is the query.Try with -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guest ";
if ($_POST['include2'] == "yes") {
$guestNameLast = isset($_POST['guestNameLast']) ? $_POST['guestNameLast'] :     '';
$query .= " WHERE ";
$query .= "guestNameLast LIKE '%$guestNameLast%' ";
$msg .="guest that <b>" . $guestNameLast . "</b><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to the where clause. So if `$_POST['guestNameLast']` is empty it win't throw an error:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guest WHERE 1=1 ";
if ($_POST['include2'] == "yes") {
$guestNameLast = isset($_POST['guestNameLast']) ? $_POST['guestNameLast'] :     '';
$query .= " AND guestNameLast LIKE '%$guestNameLast%' ";
$msg .="guest that <b>" . $guestNameLast . "</b><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add WHERE clause and AND in If condition also check that $_POST['guestNameLast'] is not empty**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guest WHERE 1 ";
if ($_POST['include2'] == "yes") 
{
if(isset($_POST['guestNameLast']) && ($_POST['guestNameLast'] != ""))
 {
 $guestNameLast = trim($_POST['guestNameLast']);
$query .= " AND guestNameLast LIKE '%$guestNameLast%' ";
 }


$msg .="guest that <b>" . $guestNameLast . "</b><br/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the WHERE clause if only you have a `guestNameLast`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM guest";

if ($_POST['include2'] == "yes") {

$guestNameLast = '';
if(isset($_POST['guestNameLast']) && trim($_POST['guestNameLast']))
{
    $guestNameLast = trim($_POST['guestNameLast']);
    $query .= " WHERE  guestNameLast LIKE '%$guestNameLast%' ";
}

$msg .="guest that <b>" . $guestNameLast . "</b><br/>";
```